# find(x) returns a wrong index when used within a specific range

Tags: matlab, indexing, find

I'm using this code to find the maximum of a value in different range of values in `A(i).data`. What I'm doing is importing a txt, manually enter the center of the different ranges (`ppmdata`), set the extreme for the range (`emax` and `emin`), find their index (which are collected in the array g) and then use the index to find values in `A(i).data`.

The code is working ok until the number that I add (subract) to emax (and emin) is equal or minor 0.01. When is bigger, matlab return me an error :

```
Error in ==> NMR at 27
        Massimo=max(A(i).data(g(1,1):g(m3,1),2));
```

Open g, i not that the element g(m3,1) is completly out of scale and do not even corrisponds to a value of A(i).data (if I check for that index I got an empty cell). If i use

```
 Massimo=max(A(i).data(g(1,1):g(m3-1,1),2));
```

it works perfectly.

```
 % % Call all txt file
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.txt','Select the Excel file:', 'MultiSelect','on');
    %% Import all file
    [m1,n1]=size(filename);
A(1:n1)=struct('data',zeros(),'textdata',zeros());
for i=1:n1
    nomefile= fullfile(pathname,filename{1,i});
    A(i)=importdata(nomefile);
end
%% ask which X values to monitor
prompt = {'Insert PPM values you want to monitor:'};
dlg_title = 'PPM';
num_lines = 1;
def = {'0.78,1.00,1.18'};
ppminput = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
ppmdata = str2num(ppminput{:});
%% Found the maxima for each X value in a range emin<X<emax
g=zeros();
[m2,n2]=size(ppmdata);
result=struct('data',zeros(),'name','', 'columnheading','');
for i=1:n1 % ciclo per mettere il nome
    for j=1:n2 %ciclo per mettere il dato
        emax=(ppmdata(1,j)+0.1;
        emin=(ppmdata(1,j)-0.1);
        g=find((A(i).data<emax) & (A(i).data>emin));
        [m3,n3]=size(g);
        Massimo=max(A(i).data(g(1,1):g(m3,1),2));
        if Massimo<0
            result.data(i,j)=0;
            result.columnheading{1,j}=['PPM:', ' ', num2str(ppmdata(1,j))];
        else
            result.data(i,j)=Massimo;
            result.columnheading{1,j}=['PPM:', ' ', num2str(ppmdata(1,j))];
        end
    end
    result.name{i,1}=A(i).textdata(19,1);
end
for i=1:n1
    for j=1:n2 %ciclo per mettere il dato
        result.data(i,n2+j)=((result.data(i,j)/sum(result.data(i,1:n2)))*100);
        result.columnheading{1,j+n2}=['Percentage:', ' ', num2str(ppmdata(1,j))];
    end

end
```

Comment: So what error do you get. Also, if you use `dbstop if error` what are the sizes and values of the relevant variables in the line that the error occurs?

Comment: the error (which I tought I put in the question) is `??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions`. At the brake point `g=(635,1)` and its values are ok (so they actually correspond to index in the matrix `A(i).data` from 48276 to 48909) with exception of `g(635,1)` which is 89461. `emax` and `emin` are 1.28 and 1.08. Value `g(635,1)` is the reason of the error, but i don't understand why. If I change 0.1 with 0.01 it run smoothly with g being a 63x1 array –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you try to index outside a variable.

As this is the line where the error occurs:

```
Massimo=max(A(i).data(g(1,1):g(m3,1),2));
```

There are only a few options:

1. `A` has less than `i` elements
2. `size(g)` is less than `[m3 1]`
3. `size(A(i).data)` is less than `[g(m3,1) 2]` (which is [89461 2])

Based on your description I would guess that the third case is your problem and that the length of your `A(i).data` variable is less than 89461.

My guess is that it goes wrong in this line:

```
g=find((A(i).data<emax) & (A(i).data>emin))
```

Perhaps you only want to search in the first or second column of `A(i).data`. If it is the first you can do:

```
g=find((A(i).data(:,1)<emax) & (A(i).data(:,1)>emin))
```

---

**Example of this problem**

Suppose you have a matrix `M`:

```
M = [1 3; 5 7]
```

If you try finding small values like this it will go well (by coincidence)

```
find(M<2)  % Returns 1
```

However, if you put your treshold as such that it is met by a value in the second column, you will run into trouble:

```
find(M<4)  % Returns 1 and 3
```

What you would need to do is:

```
find(M(:,1)<4) % Returns 1
```

The reason that you didn't run into problems for certain values, is not because you used the right commands, but because the numbers were in your favor.

Comment: Hi Dennis , the answer was definitely number 3 as A(i).data=(65536, 2). Trying the way you suggested everything go smoothly. I still do not understand why with 'g=find((A(i).data<emax) & (A(i).data>emin))` was working with some values and with other no. If you could give an explanation will be great, otherwise thx anyway –  Michele Carboni 5 mins ago

Comment: @MicheleCarboni See my updated answer including example

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Actually, after making your changing, it appeared quite obvious what was the reason and how stupid I was not thinking about it. Thanks again! Michele